# Android listview scroll add more json data?

Tags: android, json, listview, commonsware-cwac, onscrolllistener

I have a custom listview that retrieve country data through json
and there are about 100 data that i have to show it in android

if i show it directly to android it take too long to loading,
so now i want to implement scroll load more to my apps so i just have to load 10 data at first and when scroll down it will load another 10

the problem is how to make it work.. i found many ways to how to do it in this site and other site like using `onscrolllistener` but i have to change my php to pagination and i don't want it ( maybe my last option ), the other ways i found is `endless adapter`, i don't know i have to change my php code or not to use endless adapter because i don't know how to implement it and i can't found any simple example that use json and endless adapter together

so is there any way how to implement scroll to load more without changing my code alot

this is my code

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {

static final String URL = "my URL";
static final String URL_TITLE = "world";
static final String URL_ID = "rank";
static final String URL_COUNTRY = "country";
static final String URL_THUMB = "flag";
JSONArray contacts = null;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(URL_TITLE);

            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString(URL_ID);
                String country = c.getString(URL_COUNTRY);
                String thumb = c.getString(URL_THUMB);

                map.put(URL_ID, id);
                map.put(URL_COUNTRY, country);
                map.put(URL_THUMB, thumb);

                countryList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, countryList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);   
}   
}
```

I already search for 2 days without find any example that can work with this code

please help me how to make my code can load more when scrolling, and if can please give me simple example about it

thanks

Comment: But you will HAVE to change PHP to pagination. How else are you going to get the data in stages? This doesn't work like the data from server to client flows continuously while the database reads it. PHP will construct the entire response and only then send it back to the client. Pagination is a must in this case.

Comment: to load 100 items from json directly to ListView not take too long, if you retrieve your json from web service i think this is what take to long.

Comment: @velis hi, thanks but i think i found some code snippet that using endless adapter and don't need to change the php ( i don't know the code work or not because i don't know how to implement it )

Comment: @ConstantinCerberus i don't know but when i run it, it takes too long before all my data show and if i load 10 data first and another data after i scroll, i thinks it's better to see rather than all 100 data directly

Comment: @Dirus put some logs in code to see in logCat how long its take to recive your data from server and logs to creating listview with items after that you will know what take to long, also you can read this thing https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the concept of Load More List view in order to accomplish the thing that you are talking about.

Here's one [example](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore).You will get many examples that uses load more list view in Android on internet.

You can ask if you have any further queries.Happy coding :)

Comment: thanks, i already look into it and i don't how to implement it with json.. and if it fit with json i have to change my php.. do you have example that using json and can load more data when scroll ? thanks

Comment: @Dirus : check out this http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-lazy-loading-images-and-text-in-listview-from-http-json-data/

Comment: hi, that code is about json not scroll to load more.. and sorry if you misunderstanding my last comment but i mean example that using json and can scroll to load more data

Comment: Just use the logic from link given in my answer and try to display json data along with that.This much you try out by urself buddy

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/ - this may help you

Comment: thanks again, but that in androidhive is change php to pagination and i still trying to find if there is another way without changing my php